# MVC 4 Web Application can not see my controller when inheriting from TwilioController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, twilio

In my Mvc 4 website I'm starting to develop a twilio  application.  Problem is when my CallController inherits from the TwilioController the web application does not see it.  I get a:

```
"Resource Can Not Be Found Error.  This Description follows: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly".
```

However, if I relplace TwilioController with Controller, it works fine.  The TwilioController requires Twilio.TwiML.Mvc.  It must be a simple fix, but I have been hitting my head against the wall.  How do I resolve this and what am I doing wrong?

Here is my controller:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Twilio.TwiML;
using Twilio.TwiML.Mvc;

namespace XYZ.Controllers
{
    public class CallController : TwilioController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

The view is:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Can You See Me?

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and why are you using `TwilioController` instead of the standard one ?

Comment: I am using twilio to make a sms notification for our web application. Twilio recommends inherting from the twilioController to stream line the process. See the subheading "Moving Common Functionality into a TwilioController" at this URL: http//www.twilio.com/blog/2011/02/intro-building-twilio-apps-with-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: Make sure you've added Twilio dll and check if web.config file need to updated?

Comment: that tutorial is from 3 years ago, i've recently implemented Twilio, create a method in a helper class that sends out the SMS notifications rather than implementing a controller.

Comment: That is true.  The article at the top, talks about the new helper classes.  The helper class now contains twilioController. Where do you suggest I go to learn how to implement this application?

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  The code you've written looks correct to me.  Did you install the Twilio.Mvc nuget package?  Also, you only need to do this if you want to *respond* to an incoming text message.  If all you want to do is have your application send an outbound message you don't have to use the Twilio.Mvc package.  You only need the Twilio nuget package.

Comment: It had something to do with my setup. When I moved it to another application. Everything worked fine.